# Embedded linux start python from crontab with terminal access and subprocess permissions

Tags: python, cron, embedded-linux

I have an embedded linux system that I need to run a python script whenever it boots. The python script needs to have a terminal interface so the user can interact and see outputs. The script also spawns another process to transfer large amounts of data over SPI, this was written in C.

I've managed to get the script to start on launch and have terminal access by adding

`@reboot /usr/bin/screen -d -m python3 /scripts/my_script.py`

to the crontab. I can then do "screen -r" and interact with the script. However if launched in this way the script fails to start the external SPI script. In python I launch the script with subprocess.Popen

`proc=subprocess.Popen(["./spi_newpins,"-o","/media/SD/"+ latest_file"])`

and this works perfectly whenever I manually launch the script, even within screen. Just not when it is launched by crontab. Does anyone have any ideas on how to get the spi subprocess to also work from crontab?

Comment: Does this embedded Linux not have Systemd or Init?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson it does have Systemd, I'm not familiar with it though. I'm not used to Linux development, usually working on microcontrollers. Most problems I have are resolved by the 1st google results. For launching at startup it's always been crontab or adding shell scripts to /etc/init.d. Would systemd be a better solution?

Comment: If a system has Systemd, it's better to use that, but Init-style services are supported by it. If the SPI script is like a system-level service then it should probably be started that way instead of using cron. [Here](https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6) is an example guide for setting up a service. I haven't reviewed it closely, but it looks reasonably correct.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed now, I had to add an absolute path to the spi_newpins function call

proc=subprocess.Popen(["/scripts/./spi_newpins","-o","/media/SD/"+ latest_file"])